# Find a matrix $X$ such that $\exp(X) = M$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $M=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2 \\
-1 & 5
\end{bmatrix}$.
Find a matrix $X$ such that $e^X = M$, or show this is impossible.

**Attempt.** I think that this is not possible because of the convergence problem of the logarithm function. But I couldn't prove it. I've computed that $M=PDP^{-1}$ where $P=\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
0 & 6
\end{bmatrix}$. Thanks!

Comment: Do your factorization for $M-I=Q^{-1}JQ$, with $J$ diagonal. Expand $\ln(1+x)$ in power series. Then $\ln(I+(M-I))=Q^{-1}\ln(I+J)Q$.

Comment: So $J=D$. But $\ln(I+J)$ is not well defined since we have $\|D\|\not\lt 1$. Right?

Comment: That's correct, but you can compute logarithms of the diagonal anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider $e^{PXP^{-1}}$.

Comment: I think you mean $e^{P^{-1}XP}=P^{-1}e^{X}P=P^{-1}MP=D$. But so what?

Comment: @ErginSuer Now take the matrix log of both sides, a task which a lot easier for $D$ than it is for $M$.

Comment: I was thinking that the matrix log is a multivalued function. So, I've hesitated to take the matrix log of both sides.

Comment: You're looking to find at least one matrix $M$, not all of them. So it's enough to find one such logarithm. That's not hard to do for a diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries. (If that's not obvious, compute the matrix exponential of a generic diagonal matrix.)

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $P^{-1} M P= D(3,6)$ and $\exp X=M \implies X=\ln M,$
We have $$M=P D P^{-1} \implies X=\ln M= P~ \ln D ~P^{-1},$$ $\ln D = \begin{bmatrix} \ln 3 & 0 \\ 0 & \ln 6 \end{bmatrix}.$ Here we have used the result that$$f(M)=P ~f(D) P^{-1}$$ and
$$f(D)=D(\ln \lambda_1, \ln \lambda_2).$$